# Target-specific localised string catalogues with storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, storyboard

I have an application with two variants (whitelabel), implemented as two separate targets. The two applications are localised and may have slightly different user-facing strings, depending on the target.

I have split `Localized.strings` file into shared part and per-target parts. Each target compiles a shared `Localized.strings` with common strings and one of `Target.strings` variants.

Then I can choose either `NSLocalizedString()` or `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()` to look up the appropriate string, or even combine them and look up target-specific string first, if not found, fallback to the default catalogue.

So far so good.

The stumbling block is the IB files, because I can only have one strings file per storyboard/xib, I cannot include per-target variants.

I've considered a number of build-time hacks (custom scripts to merge strings files), but want to know if there is a better workaround.

Ideally, I'd like to override string lookup mechanism so it supports multiple strings catalogues and would look in target-specific catalogue first.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this. I am stuck at the same point (strings from code are OK). Scoured through a list of stack overflow Q&A. But found nothing of help (Honestly surprised something as basic as this can be so painful).

Comment: @Dibzmania My solution was to stop using Interface Builder. Interface builder is bad and Apple ought to be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: I would not say that the whole concept of IB is terrible but certain parts of it definitely are. In my case it's just 4-5 strings from IB which I need to be different per target and as such I am handling it via if/else in code which is terrible. Just out of curiosity, are you handwriting your your UI since you said you stopped using IB

Comment: @Dibzmania Oh yes, the concept is not bad, it's fine, it's just Apple's IB that is bad. And yes I ended up hand-writing layout code. I have a kind of ad-hoc mini-DSL going to do layouts, sticking to stack views where I can to simplify auto-layout.

Comment: not sure what does IB have to do with anything, as you can use Model to have any kind of text (per target per language), and then pull that text through outlet connection into that view..